# Linking theorem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

In 1978 Rabinowitz obtained the classical "Linking theorem", which is used to solve, for example the classical problem:

$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = \lambda u + |u|^{p-2}u, \Omega \\
u = 0, \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
where $\lambda > \lambda_1$ (the first eigenvalue of $(-\Delta, H^1_0(\Omega))$.

Forgive me if this question is "dumb", but i'm beginner in variational methods. But I would like to know why this result from Rabinowitz gets its name and what exactly does it mean to say "establish a linking structure for the functional". I appreciate any help and any advice.